# PHPStorm 2017.1 fails running remoted phpcs: "ERROR: The file ~/.phpstorm_helpers/... does not exist"

Tags: php, phpstorm

**QUESTION UPDATE**: *I had mistakenly used the revision number for PHPStorm. The correct version is 2017.1, not 2017.3 as initially stated*.

I recently updated to the latest PHPStorm (2017.1 March) and PHPcs does no longer work, giving an error instead. This is the PHPStorm version:

```
PhpStorm 2017.1
Build #PS-171.3780.104, built on March 21, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1
```

I remember there being a similar error in 2017.1 January, which had then been fixed in February.

I've already inspected the configuration and it is OK and it validates correctly; apparently, the remote Code Sniffer (version 2.7.0 on up-to-date Ubuntu 16.04-LTS) is either not running correctly or is being invoked with the wrong parameters (looks more probable).

The error is:

```
PHP Code Sniffer
        phpcs: ERROR: The file "/home/lserni/.phpstorm_helpers/phpcs_temp.tmp/PHP" does not exist.

        Usage: phpcs [-nwlsaepqvi] [-d key[=value]] [--colors] [--no-colors] [--stdin-path=<stdinPath>]
        [--report=<report>] [--report-file=<reportFile>] [--report-<report>=<reportFile>] ...
        [--report-width=<reportWidth>] [--generator=<generator>] [--tab-width=<tabWidth>]
        [--severity=<severity>] [--error-severity=<severity>] [--warning-severity=<severity>]
        [--runtime-set key value] [--config-set key value] [--config-delete key] [--config-show]
        [--standard=<standard>] [--sniffs=<sniffs>] [--exclude=<sniffs>] [--encoding=<encoding>]
        [--extensions=<extensions>] [--ignore=<patterns>] [--bootstrap=<bootstrap>]
        [--file-list=<fileList>] <file> ...
        Set
```

Downgrading to February version, as expected, solves the problem (this was not happening before the upgrade). I wanted to update because I expect this to fix [an annoying bug that I don't want to work around](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28091).

Before I file a bug - which I'm not too comfortable with, since my configuration isn't straight out of the box - does anyone know what the problem is, or does anyone care to guess? PHPStorm configuration was correct *for the previous revision*, but it might well be the case that the previous one let me get away with some stupidity I came up with, that is now biting me with the current revision.

Comment: You didn't supply the error.  You should downgrade to 2017.2 and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry. Updated answer. As you see, this is a standard "syntax error" message. I'm wondering if the phpcs invocation is using a file *with spaces in the name*, and they forgot the quotes. Except that I'm not using any file with spaces in the name, and none called "PHP something". Actually there are no "PHP something" files in my PC except for a "PHP Object Dumps.xml" that was also present in 2017.2 .

Comment: We are always glad to help, but please don't put "Solved" in the title of your question. Within our community, the fact that you designated an answer as the official solution already shows us that the problem has been solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so PHPStorm executes code remotely on my machine. I can debug that.

It turns out that to analyze a file, PHPStorm uploads the file via SFTP to my machine, as expected. Then it invokes phpcs from SSH, also as expected.

What is not expected is that I see **two** invocations (rather I *would* see two if the first didn't crash, see below). The first one attempts to run Code Sniffer against a file called "PHP Console", that *does* exist and *is* uploaded on my machine, except it is zero bytes in length (and therefore fails basic PHPCS validation; it does not even have short tags).

Then PHPStorm invokes phpcs without quotes, so asks for

```
...phpcs PHP Console --format=XML etc.
```

and of course phpcs tries to open a file called "PHP", and fails. Therefore it displays an error and it stops, never going on to sniff the real file I want sniffed.

## Resolution

I prepared a different binary that invokes phpcs and called it `/usr/local/bin/phpcs-phpstorm`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "PHP" = "$1" ]; then
        # Output a PHPCS message saying "This file is OK, go on."
        cat <<-HERE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpcs version="2.7.0"></phpcs>
HERE
        exit 0
fi

# Launch the true phpcs. And since we're here, use also my own standard.
# (I need to find out how to update PHPCS smell sets in PHPStorm)

/usr/bin/phpcs --standard=/home/lserni/phpstorm-phpcs-ruleset.xml $*
```

I then told PHPStorm that my remote PHPCS was called `/usr/local/bin/phpcs-phpstorm`.

This way, two instances of phpcs are launched - the first reports no error and terminates immediately, and at that point the second phpcs is launched against the real PHP file copied on the machine. The time taken by the first run is negligible since the real phpcs is not even loaded.

Not elegant, but whatever works.